# Avoid double conversion from integer while reading data using Gson

Tags: java, gson, typetoken

I am saving data using json in aerospike:

```
new Gson().toJson(data)
```

While reading, I am using typetoken:

```
Type type = new TypeToken<Map<String, Object>>() {
                        }.getType();
Map<String, Map<String, Object>> myMap = new Gson().fromJson(dataFromCache, type);
```

The issue with above conversion is, that all integers are converted into doubles. How can I stop the conversion?

Comment: please share your json

Comment: Give me a minute

Answer (score 3):

This is a well-known issue in Gson.
By default, Gson always deserializes JSON numbers that are declared as `Object` to `Double` causing some precision loss for long integer values.
`Object` serializers/deserializers cannot be overridden by design, so you cannot change its behavior.
If you can narrow down the declaration type to `Number`, Gson would deserialize the numbers to `com.google.gson.internal.LazilyParsedNumber` that holds a backing string and can parse it to any "built-in" numeric type lazily (say, `longValue()` and `doubleValue()` can return an appropriate value).
If you can narrow down even more, it would work even better.
Example:

```java
final String json = "[1,4,9]";
final Iterable<? extends Type> types = ImmutableList.of(
        new TypeToken<Collection<Object>>() {}.getType(),
        new TypeToken<Collection<Number>>() {}.getType(),
        new TypeToken<Collection<Integer>>() {}.getType()
);
for ( final Type type : types ) {
    System.out.print(type);
    System.out.print(": ");
    System.out.println();
    for ( final Object value : gson.<Iterable<?>>fromJson(json, type) ) {
        System.out.print('\t');
        System.out.print(value);
        System.out.print(' ');
        System.out.println(value.getClass());
    }
}
```

would produce the following output:

```
java.util.Collection<java.lang.Object>: 
    1.0 class java.lang.Double
    4.0 class java.lang.Double
    9.0 class java.lang.Double
java.util.Collection<java.lang.Number>: 
    1 class com.google.gson.internal.LazilyParsedNumber
    4 class com.google.gson.internal.LazilyParsedNumber
    9 class com.google.gson.internal.LazilyParsedNumber
java.util.Collection<java.lang.Integer>: 
    1 class java.lang.Integer
    4 class java.lang.Integer
    9 class java.lang.Integer
```

Simply speaking, you cannot do it for `Object`s at least as of Gson 2.8.4, but you can specify a more concrete type if it's fine for you.
I was trying to [fix](https://github.com/google/gson/pull/1290) the issue, but the fix is still in the pre-review state.